# Zurb top bar nav link not working

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I have the following code that essentially a copy and paste job from the Zurb Foundation site that creates a top bar nav with a menu dropdown on the right hand side. It works correctly when the page is initially loaded however after clicking on the link to the `root_path`, it navigating to the root and then clicking on the dropdown a `#` is appended to the URL and then clicking on the links from the dropdown no longer works. To get them to work i have to reload the page.

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation" data-options="is_hover: false" >
 <ul class="title-area">
  <li class="name">
    <h1><%= link_to "Cost Planner", root_path %></h1>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <section class="top-bar-section">
  <ul class="right">
  <li class="has-dropdown">
    <% if current_user %>
      <a href="#"><%= current_user.username %></a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><%= link_to "My Activities", user_activities_path(current_user)  %></li>
        <li><%= button_to "Log out", session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
      </ul>  
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Log in", new_session_path %>
    <% end %>
  </li>
  </ul>
 </section>
</nav>
```

Comment: This might actually be a problem with turbolinks, where the page isn't really reloaded when you click on links, but rather the content is switched out with ajax, or some other sort of magic. I have come across similar issues which turned out to be turbolinks related. Try switching it off an see if that helps.

Comment: yea you're right, turning off turbolinks fixes it but have you found a work around that still allows you to have turbolinks on?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't remember what I did to fix it, if I ever was able to. Maybe you have to tweak how links are generated. My suggestion: Manually try to make the links with different variations, and see if anything works, then tweak how the links are generated.